# Sync interbase database tables to SQL Server Database using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, interbase

I need to sync SQL server database with the Interbase DB. Interbase is the live DB and main application works on this. Now customer wants to create an SQL server database and sync it with the live interbase database once everyday. I want to create an application, which can be scheduled to compare both Interbase and SQL Server databases and merge the SQL Server with all changes from the Interbase Server. Is there any way to do this using c# .Net?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Microsoft Sync framework - it's designed to do what you want, though not sure if there's a plug in for Interbase.